# Attempt to define limit of a sequence of surreal numbers

Tags: general-topology, ordinals, nonstandard-analysis, surreal-numbers

For sake of well-definedness, here we consider only ordinals less than the first uncountable ordinal, $\Omega$. Just like $\infty$ in the notation $\lim_{n→\infty}$ is essentially $\omega$, $\Omega$ will be the new $\infty$. Likewise, surreal numbers will be capped by $\pm\Omega$.

I attempted to define the notion of **limit of a sequence to arbitrary ordinal**. It's just an extension of the usual $\epsilon$-$N$ definition:

$$
\lim_{n→O} f(n) = x \overset{\text{def.}}{\iff} \forall(\epsilon>0) \quad \exists(N<O) \quad \forall(n \text{ s.t. } N<n<O) \quad |f(n)-x|<\epsilon
$$

Where $\epsilon$ is real, $O$ is a limit ordinal, and $N$ and $n$ are ordinals.

Note that in this notion, the notion of **uncountable summation** follows. One might wonder whether the following limit converges:

$$
\lim_{n→\Omega}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k^2}
$$

This makes sense only if $f$ is supposed to be a sequence of surreal numbers. But generally and unfortunately, limit doesn't uniquely exist amongst surreal numbers. For example, $\lim_{n→\omega}\frac1n$ converges to zero *and* every infinitesimal.

Furthermore, in this definition, $\lim_{n→\omega}n$ diverges. By the notion of a limit ordinal, $\lim_{n→\omega}n = \omega$ must satisfy.

To summarize, the definition above is flawed, and this question asks for a topology on surreal numbers such that:

- Surreal numbers form a topological field
- $\mathbb{R}$ as a subspace preserves its order topology
- The countable ordinals as a subspace preserves its order topology

Comment: I don't think $\frac{1}{n}$ approches $0$ as $n$ goes to $\omega$, unless in your definition your require $\varepsilon>0$ *and* $\varepsilon\in\Bbb{R}$. Otherwise, for $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{\omega}$, you don't have $\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon$ for any $n<\omega$.

Comment: @Cronus Well, my goal is to incorporate **both** the countable ordinals and the standard analysis. That's why I required $\epsilon$ to be real.

Comment: If you want to have both real numbers and ordinal numbers as topological subspaces, then you cannot have Haussdorff field topologies. Indeed the sequence $(\frac{1}{n+1})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ will converge both to $0$ and $\omega^{-1}$. Likewise, the sequence $(n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ will converge both to $\omega$ and each $\omega-k$ or $\frac{\omega}{k}$ or $(\omega)^{\frac{1}{k}}$ for $0<k \in \mathbb{N}$...

Comment: @nombre That's too heartbreaking. T_T

Comment: You could have the first two conditions by taking as closed sets those which contain every limit of their convergent sequences as defined in your question. Then the sequence $(n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge to $\omega$, but this is rather a good thing because $\omega$ and $\omega-k$ and so on cannot be distinguished from a purely field theoretic point of view.

Comment: There is also a natural notion of convergence using sign sequences: a sequence $(u_{\beta})_{\beta<\lambda}$ converges to a number $x$ if for every initial segment $s$ of its sign sequence, there is an ordinal $\gamma$ such that $s$ is an initial segment of $u_{\beta}$ for all $\beta>\gamma$. This preserves ordinal and real limits. But the topology it generates (by taking closed sets as limit-closed sets) is not a topology of topological field. Also this notion of limit should be modified in order to make it Haussdorf.

Comment: @nombre Well, I guess the word "heartbreaking" was an overkill. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer, but a comment: a field topology that would accomodate ordinal numbers would probably look wierd.

First note that in a topological field $F$, translations and non-zero homotheties and the multiplicative inversion are homeomorphisms (the latter on $F^{\times}$).

Consider a countable ordinal $\lambda$ of the form $\lambda = \omega^{\mu},\mu>0$. Every neighborhood $U$ of $\lambda$ in $\mathbf{No}$ (taken here to be the set of surreal numbers with length $<\Omega$) must contain some number $x$ with $x<\frac{\lambda}{2}$. Indeed $\Omega \cap U$ must contain some $\gamma$ for $\gamma<\lambda$. So any neighborhood $V=(V +\lambda)-\lambda$ of $0$ must contain a number $y$ with $y<-\frac{\lambda}{2}$. Since this is true for any $\lambda$ and any neighborhood $U$, we see by translations that each non-empty open set must be coinitial in $\mathbf{No}$. By symmetry, any non-empty open subset is also cofinal.

So every interval $(a,+\infty)$ is dense. Let $O$ be an open neighborhood of $1$ which does not contain $0$. For each $a\in \mathbf{No}^{>0}$, the set $O^{-1}$ intersects $(a,+\infty)$, so $O$ intersects $(0,a^{-1})$. By using homotheties, we see that any non-empty open subset which does not contain $0$ intersects any $(0,a^{-1})$, so any open interval containing $0$ is dense in $\mathbf{No}^{\times}$, hence in $\mathbf{No}$. So any non-empty open interval is dense.

So you'll have generalized sequences with values in $(-1,1)$ which tend to $\omega$.